# Finding specific string and adding that string to column

Tags: r, string, gsub, grepl

I would like to first for a string in a vector and replace it with a match vector with either same length or 1. I have used the qdap package which has the function multigsub. Although it just replaces everything. Example of desired outputs (and a solution with loop). Additionally I would not like that "Jabad" is found.

```
df1 <- data.frame(string = c("Erik is pretty good", "Fred is regular", "James is bad", "Jabad is extra"))

replacements <- c("good", "regular", "bad")

df1$status <- NA

for(i in 1:3){

  df1[grepl(replacements[i], df1$string), "status"] <- replacements[i]

}

df1
```

Second example

```
df1$status <- "Status unknown"

for(i in 1:3){

  df1[grepl(replacements[i], df1$string), "status"] <- "Status known"


}

df1
```

Looking for something similar to multigsub where is can specify two vectors, for example c("... Good ...", "... Best ...", "... Regular ...", "... Extra" ...) which are to be replaced with
c("Good", "Good", "Regular", "Best"). multigsub will in this case though return me the text before/after the word (indicate by ... in this example).

Comment: add word boundaries. i.e. `df1[grepl(paste0('\\b', replacements[i], '\\b'), df1$string), "status"] <- replacements[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your case this is what you want. It uses the `str_extract` function from the library `stringr`.

I've added a few cases to demonstrate

The variable `s` will hold the strings you are searching for while `r` will hold the replacements for the found values.

```
library(stringr)

df = structure(list(string = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("Erik is pretty good",
"Fred is regular", "Jabad is extra", "Jabad is unknown", "James is bad",
"John is best"), class = "factor")), .Names = "string", row.names = c(NA,
-6L), class = "data.frame")

s = c('good', 'best', 'regular', 'bad', 'extra')
r = c('Good', 'Good', 'Regular', 'Bad', 'Best')
names(r) <- s

pat = paste0("\\b(", paste0(s, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")

z = str_extract(df$string, pat)

# Lookup function will return NA when input is NA 
lookup <- function(x, s, r){
    i = match(x, s)
    if(is.na(i)) return(NA)
    r[[i]]
}

df$Status = sapply(z, lookup, s=s, r=r)

df = transform(df, Status2 = ifelse(is.na(Status), "Status Unknown", "Status Known"))
```

The resulting data.frame is:

```
               string  Status        Status2
1 Erik is pretty good    Good   Status Known
2     Fred is regular Regular   Status Known
3        James is bad     Bad   Status Known
4      Jabad is extra    Best   Status Known
5    Jabad is unknown    <NA> Status Unknown
6        John is best    Good   Status Known
```

Comment: str_extract  was perfect, thanks. I used it together with multisub.